# jQuery .prop is not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add "disabled" attr to button when sending data, but it's not working.  `beforeSend` and `complete` methods are working.

```
function DoSome() {                             
    var s = "";
    $.ajax({url: '/DoSome',
    type: 'post',
    data :  { ... },
    async : false,
    beforeSend : function(){
       jQuery('#DoItButtonID').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    },
    complete : function(){
        jQuery('#DoItButtonID').removeAttr("disabled");
    },
    success : function(data) {
         s = data;
    },dataType: 'json'})

return s;   
}  DoSome();
```

Button :

```
<button type="submit" class="small ui button hover" id="DoItButtonID">Do it</button>
```

Comment: I dont see `addClass` being called anywhere. Also, do you see any console log errors?

Comment: I don't want to `addClass` , I want to make it disabled. When I add class, it's still clickable. Also no error.

Comment: Then why do you claim `addClass` isn't working?!

Comment: Ok. You might want to edit the question title. Also, can you reproduce the error with a fiddle with only the relevant parts of the code ?

Comment: Maybe use `.attr` instead of `.prop`?

Comment: Still not working according to your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for disabling

```
jQuery('#DoItButtonID').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

this one to remove disable

```
jQuery('#DoItButtonID').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: Try correct this `type: 'post'` to `type: 'POST',`,and `jQuery(...)` to `$(...)`